# DDD: What are good reasons for you to loosely-couple Entities?

Tags: interface, domain-driven-design, loose-coupling

Back in December, there was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352618/should-every-single-object-have-an-interface-and-all-objects-loosely-coupled) that was answered with "it is ok to use concret types [for simple object]".

But I keep seeing more and more simple entities with interfaces in sample projects, and even the very large Enterprise application I just took control over (counting 89 interfaces and going).

Is it that people are not picking the best approach, and just shotgunning the project with the "my project is loosely-coupled!" approach?

Or, am I missing something.  I can unit test with concret types for my IService, IFactory and IRepository implmentations I have (and works quite well).  I am also building my first "Anticorruption Layer" for abstracting a lot of these 3rd party tools out away from the main domain.  This anticorruption layer has a number of Facades, Translators, and Adapters - all of which are loosely coupled (or planned to be).

So, is there something I missing about Entities having Interfaces?

```
public interface IContent
{
  Int32 ContentID {get; set;}
}

IList<IContent> list = new List();
```

Edit: I should also mention that that the enterprise app I have that has all of these interfaces, has zero unit tests.  lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more important that entities that have *responsibility* conform to an interface than it is for simple data objects. If you can define the entity in terms of methods, then, yes, you'll benefit from an interface. I can't see that an object that will simply be used as a DTO within the application gains any great advantage by having an interface.

That said, there is certainly benefit from abstracting away "entities" created by a third party tool, or a framework like L2S, in my opinion.