# How coupled should a domain model be? Should all aggregate roots be interfaces?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model, loose-coupling

We're finally building a domain model.  The domain model includes interfaces for loosely coupling domain objects to persistence.   I'm however wondering how coupled the domain model objects should be to each other.

Does *Order* point to a *Customer* or to an *ICustomer*?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352618/should-every-single-object-have-an-interface-and-all-objects-loosely-coupled) mentions problems with aggressively de-coupling objects and seems to discourage "going overboard with [interfaces]".   I however don't see how I can truly unit test my domain entities unless I can mock the other entities they depend on, which requires loose coupling.

I'm also uncertain about how realistic it is to want a domain model in which pieces could be swapped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't mind using concrete collaborators in unit tests when the collaborator:

1) Has a comprehensive set of unit tests that clearly specifies its behavior.

2) Isn't difficult to arrange.

3) Doesn't utilize external resources (or [break any of these related guidelines](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=126923)).

We do this all the time with framework classes (say, `DateTime` or `string`) - unless an aggregate's child is unusually complex, you should be able to trust it too.

Answer (score 0):

> The domain model includes interfaces for loosely coupling domain objects to persistence.

The persistence **persists** your objects. It knows your object in order to persist them. Decoupling the persistence from the model does not give you anything. Any change in the domain will have to be reflected in the persistence layer,

When doing DDD you work with the domain expert to identify the ubiquitous language, which you then represent in code. I have yet to see a domain expert mentioning an interface. Decouple the ARs in your model by identifying the right concepts in your domain. You might have interfaces defined for some domain services, but make sure they are real service providers in your domain and not some concepts you missed.

> I'm also uncertain about how realistic it is to want a domain model in which pieces could be swapped out.

You are right, it's not realistic. You might swap the implementation for a certain service provider, but entities in an AR? I don't think so.

Comment: I'm aware that my persistence layer will be coupled to the dm.  It's the other way around that you want to stay away from:  coupling your DM to your persistence.  But how will I unit test if everything is coupled together?

Comment: Having persistence components inside the ARs is not recommended. That is if your Order AR has a ICustomerRepository dependency you should go back and rethink that.

Comment: As for testing, you should test your entities as a unit, with their dependent entities and VOs. If they seem to be to interconnected, applying [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)) principles to your entities might help.

Answer (score 0):

When doing DDD you don't want to 'truly decouple entities'. You should start by partitioning your domain model into Aggregates which should be decoupled. Inside Aggregates there is no need to mock anything because an Aggregate should be treated as a 'unit' for unit tests.

Also, moving as much behavior as possible to Value Object will help you make your domain model testable as Value Objects (which are, by definition, immutable) are very easy to test.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that my aggregates should be decoupled?   My aggregates are built such that there's a clean line of where one aggregate ends and the other starts such that persistence and deletes are easy to understand  (1 repo per agg).  However, in the customary example,  I see the Order aggregate having a direct reference to the Customer aggregate.